# Unable to get property 'childNodes' of undefined or null reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, dhtml, scriptaculous

We are doing a cross browser compatibility for a tool which was built over 8 years ago. The tool works only with IE7. Now we are doing the compatibility for higher IE versions and other browsers as well. While checking in IE8 and above, its throwing an error saying "able to get property 'childNodes' of undefined or null reference" in effects.js of script.aculo.us

Here's the bit where its throwing the error -

```
var Enumerable = {
each: function(iterator) {
var index = 0;
try {
this._each(function(value) {
try {
  iterator(value, index++);
} catch (e) {
  if (e != $continue) throw e;
}
});
} 
catch (e) {
if (e != $break) throw e; 
}
},
```

Since it was built 8 years ago, i believe this error is because of the very old versions of DHTMLX (1.5) and old version of script.aculo.us is used. But not sure though. Any idea about this error? Thanks.